# Multiple div addClass and increment suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I'm working on masonry here I'm adding classes dynamically to the `.gallery-items` I append classes `.column1, .column1`  and for the `.mansory-item` appending `.image-holder` with suffix increment.
The main parent div is `.masonry-grid` so I have multiple `.masonry-grid` div's.

So, the first parent div appending `.image-holder` with suffix, the increment is working fine.

But for the second parent increment starting from 6,7,8 n all. I want to start with 1,2,3 and 4,5 same like the first div to all parent div's.

I had tried using `$(this)` but unable to achieve can anyone suggest how I can achieve the desired output?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery-items:nth-of-type(odd)').addClass('column1');
  $('.gallery-items:nth-of-type(even)').addClass('column2');

  $('.masonry-grid').each(function() {
    $(".column1").children('.mansory-item').each(function(i) {
      $(this).addClass("image-holder" + (i + 1));
    });
    $(".column2").children('.mansory-item').each(function(i) {
      $(this).addClass("image-holder" + (i + 4));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry-grid">
  <div class="gallery-items">
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-items">
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="masonry-grid">
  <div class="gallery-items">
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-items">
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$(this).find` instead of `$(".column1").children` as the former would give you children of that particular element with choice of selector while the later gives you all `.column1` elements:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery-items:nth-of-type(odd)').addClass('column1');
  $('.gallery-items:nth-of-type(even)').addClass('column2');

  $('.masonry-grid').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.column1 .mansory-item').each(function(i) {
      $(this).addClass("image-holder" + (i + 1));
    });
    $(this).find('.column2 .mansory-item').each(function(i) {
      $(this).addClass("image-holder" + (i + 4));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry-grid">
  <div class="gallery-items">
    <div class="mansory-item">1
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">2
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-items">
    <div class="mansory-item">4
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="masonry-grid">
  <div class="gallery-items">
    <div class="mansory-item">6
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">7
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">8
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-items">
    <div class="mansory-item">9
    </div>
    <div class="mansory-item">10
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```